# Proper naming of PID regulators

Tags: pid

I was wondering either there is any special naming for regulators that:

- Outputs unit is the same as inputs, ie. velocity [m/s] as input and velocity as output [m/s].
- Outputs unit is different than inputs, ie. position as input [m], velocity as output [/m/s]

I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Do you have any examples of where people make a distinction between the two? Generally speaking, when writing a PID controller, you either work with the units you have (and account for that in your gains), or convert them to something more sensible on input to or output from the PID controller.

Comment: Yes, for example. Lets say two pid controllers are connected in series. The first one is pos controller and it has position as input and velocity as output. The second one is velocity controller that gets the velocity on its input and outputs regulated velocity as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that helps explain what you mean, but in any case, I don't think there are any industry standard terms for what you appear to be describing. If I were you, I would chose a term (say homogeneous and heterogeneous input/output PID) and then explicitly define that this is what you mean by these terms.

Comment: Also, on stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).

Comment: In reference to [SteveO's answer](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/10188/37) for your two examples, what units would the control input be? Typically control input, feedback input and output variable would often be different units, as part of the job of a PID controller is to translate a requirement into an actuation in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean? The units at what point in the control loop? You can't exactly have a speed reference input to a PID controller and use a *position* feedback.

Similarly, if you're just looking strictly at the inputs and outputs of the PID block itself, then the units are *always* different. That is, for a speed controller, you have:

- (P)roportional gain output: [Speed ref] - [Speed fbk]  (Units of **dist/time**)
- (I)ntegral gain output: [Pos ref] - [Pos fbk]  (Units of 
  **dist**)
- (D)erivative gain output: [Accel ref] - [Accel fbk]  (Units of **dist/time^2**)

So, where the input of a PID controller are a particular unit, the I/D aspects of the PID controller *require* the output units to always be different. This is typically just the "control signal" and inputs to whatever the plant is.

Again I'll ask, what are the inputs and outputs you are considering? In and out of the PID block, or input/output as in the reference and feedback?

If you mean reference and feedback (inputs and outputs to the entire control system), then generally you have:

- SISO - **S**ingle **I**nput **S**ingle **O**utput, meaning that there is one input and one output. These outputs should be the same units to make any sense.
- MIMO - **M**ultiple **I**nput **M**ultiple **O**utput, meaning that there are multiple inputs and multiple outputs. This is generally some state feedback or LQR controller, and here the units can be mixed as you're trying to control the *system* instead of a particular *parameter*.

Consider any scenario when you might want to try using a feedback in units other than the reference units. What then are you trying to do? For instance, why would you want to use acceleration as a feedback for a speed reference? Maybe you want to control min/max acceleration *while you try to achieve a particular speed*, or you want to control speed *while you try to achieve a particular position*, but I'll point out that in these scenarios you are trying to control **two** parameters (speed and position, speed and acceleration, etc.), and thus it's a MIMO system (Multiple input - speed ref and [X] limits, multiple output - speed and [X]).

Comment: nitpick: "*the units are always different*", well except for a pure P controller. For anything else, the units are different even within just the output, because the PID output of the mentioned speed controller would be a sum of speed, position and acceleration values.

Comment: I understand the point. So does that mean that for any given PID, the output is always unitless?

Comment: @BendingUnit22 - Lol I *knew* someone was going to say something. I almost pointed that out in the post but didn't.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło - Well, not unitless exactly, but a mix of units. Open-loop control (without feedback) would pass the reference signal (with its units) to the plant. A simple proportional closed-loop controller would, as BendingUnit22 noted, also pass the same units as the reference signal to the plant. The I/D aspects of the PID controller can be viewed as "adjustments" to the proportional controller, but *to be technically correct*, they also add the integral and derivative units of the reference signal to the control signal. I don't think there is a term for that, but it's not unitless.

Comment: Another example of a system with identical input and output units would be one which does force control using piezo cells for both actuation and feedback. Even in such a system, if you are trying to do something like dampen vibrations, you may end up with something much more complex than s simple proportional controller.

Answer (score 2):

I name them by the controlled parameter(s), such as *velocity controller* or *position controller*.   For clarity it is sometimes helpful to include the feedback variable(s):  *velocity controller with position feedback*. I am not aware of any notational standards.

Comment: This answer seems to be basing name on the control variable rather than on the input or output variables, as the question asks.

Comment: @MarkBooth, I took the question as what to name a regulator, with two specific examples given in the question.  I do not read those two examples as requesting a specific convention that uses the inputs and outputs in the name.  Since I do not typically name controllers based on inputs and outputs, but rather on the controlled parameter, I believe this does answer the OP question.  For example, a velocity controller would be my name for the first example given in the question.

Comment: I agree Steve, which is why I've been trying to clarify the question.